# What is $ dollar sign in hyperledger composer?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In query language _$ sign is used frequently, what does this mean and also every class keyword has a dollar prefix. What is the significance/meaning of $ and _$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

Queries may embed parameters using the _$ syntax. Note that query parameters must be primitive types (String, Integer, Double, Long, Boolean, DateTime), a Relationship or an Enumeration.

The named query below is defined in terms of 3 parameters:

```
query Q18 {
description: "Select all drivers aged older than PARAM"
statement:
    SELECT org.acme.Driver
        WHERE (_$ageParam < age)
            ORDER BY [lastName ASC, firstName DESC]
                LIMIT _$limitParam
                    SKIP _$skipParam
}
```

Here is the source: [Source](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/query.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `$` prefix is used by Composer to identify the type of an entity serialized to JSON. The `_$` prefix is used in the query language to create parameterized queries.